# Freeing filp->private_data in linux kernel module causes use-after-free

Tags: c, linux, linux-kernel, linux-device-driver

I'm early in learning about linux kernel modules & device drivers. I've written a basic driver that implements scull (following Linux Device Drivers 3rd ed.). The driver actually works as expected, I can open/close/read/write from the device file it creates both with things like `cp`/`cat` and also with direct syscalls in a userspace program.

The next chapter of the book is all about debugging, so I recompiled the kernel with more debugging features turned on. I try writing to the device same as before, and I'm warned about a use-after-free error. "`BUG: KASAN: use-after-free in cdev_put+0x4c/0x90`". Looking at the "allocated by" trace, I see the memory in question is the `cdev` allocated with

```c
cdev = kmalloc(sizeof(struct cdev), GFP_KERNEL);
```

The free occurs in my `close` function stored in the `file_operations` struct:

```c
int my_close(struct inode *inode, struct file *filp) {
    kfree(filp->private_data);
    return 0;
}
```

I should note, what is actually stored in `private_data` is a pointer to my device struct, which contains a `struct cdev`. But since the device struct contains a `struct cdev` and not a pointer to a `cdev`, I guess it would free the `cdev` too.

The call trace of the use-after-free is

```
dump_backtrace+0x0/0x460
show_stack+0x24/0x30
dump_stack_lvl+0x9c/0xd8
print_address_description.constprop.0+0x74/0x2b8
kasan_report+0x1bc/0x2ac
__asan_load8+0xbc/0xd0
cdev_put+0x4c/0x90
__fput+0x4c4/0x750
____fput+0x1c/0x30
task_work_run+0x17c/0x26c
do_notify_resume+0x2ce4/0x3060
work_pending+0xc/0x438
```

So it looks like this `cdev_put` function is using the `cdev` after it's freed in my `my_close` function. But according to the book (in chapter 3), the `close` function should "`Deallocate anything that open allocated in filp->private_data`". However, the stripped down version of scull's close function included in the book looks like

```c
int scull_release(struct inode *inode, struct file *filp)
{
    return 0;
}
```

Which does not include the free I've included.

The book also does say that the close function should "`Shut down the device on last close`"  so perhaps `private_data` shouldn't be freed until the "last" close of the file? How is the driver supposed to know if a particular close is the last close? From the other parts of the book I've read so far, keeping track of stuff like how many opens and closes have occurred is the kernel's job, not the driver. But maybe I've misunderstood.

So main question: *when* should `private_data` be freed?

Comment: Read the book carefully: '"the close function should "Deallocate anything that **open allocated** in `filp->private_data`"'. Do you allocate something in your `open` function? No. So, why do you want to free anything in the `close` function? `cdev` is allocated in the module's **init** function when character device is created. So it should be freed in the exit function after destroying the device.

Comment: There are two common ways to use `cdev`s. The first way is to use a single `cdev` for the whole character device driver (typically set up in the module init function and destroyed in the module exit function). The second way is to set up an individual `cdev` for each device (typically set up in the driver's device probe function and destroyed in the driver's device remove function). I cannot think of many situations where you would want to destroy a `cdev` in a character device's `release` file operation (unless your device creates other devices).

Comment: Yeah, like previous commenters told you, you are now learning a lesson called "Object Lifetime and how handle it".